# How do database snapshots work?

Tags: database-design, backup, snapshot, database-theory

How do database engines take consistent snapshots when writes could be happening at any time?

(A) Does the database engine block writes one table at a time while taking snapshots?

(B) Does the database engine block writes to the entire database while taking snapshots?

(C) Or, does the database engine do something more clever?

Comment: Which database system are you referring to, as that'll affect the answer? For example, the MySQL answer provided below is certainly not how SQL Server works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a MySQL DBA so will approach the question under that perspective. None of three. Snapshots is something that happens at OS level (OS that manages the disks)
If you want to take a consistent snapshot, you have to first stop your database process or fully lock the whole DB (shutdown is best practice tho) then take the snapshot and last you start the service back or release the global exclusive lock.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).